# How can I use Google Search in my C# project?

Tags: c#, document, information-retrieval

i build mini Question Answering System in C#. I need retrieve document by google Search.
What is google tools name, i can use it in my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to set up a [custom Google search engine](https://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/).  Then you also need to create a developer key, which I believe is done under [the console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

After setting that up, you can make REST style call with code such as the following, which retrieves the results as JSON:

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();

string result;
string uri;
string googleAPIKey = "your developer key";
string googleEngineID = "your search engine id";
string template = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={0}&cx={1}&q={2}&start={3}&alt=json";
int startIndex = 1;
int gathered = 0;

uri = String.Format(template, googleAPIKey, googleEngineID, "yoursearchstring", startIndex);
result = w.DownloadString(uri);
```

For extracting the information from the JSON results, you can use something like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).  It makes it extremely easy to read the information:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
```

Then you can directly access the desired information with a single line of code.

One important piece of information is that the search API free usage is extremely limited (100 requests per day).  So for a real-world application it would probably be necessary to pay for the search.  But depending on how you use it, maybe 100 requests per day is sufficient.  I wrote a little mashup using the Google search API to search for Stackoverflow site information of interest and then used the [StackExchange API](https://stackapps.com/) to retrieve the information.  For that personal use, it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it before (and it's alpha), but take a look at [Google APIs for .NET Framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) library.